# WPF DataGrid - Different cell color based on hidden value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to get up to speed on how to use DataTriggers on a DataGrid.

I have four columns in my datatable (Node, Name, Value, Flag).  Flag is a hidden column in the datagrid.

I would the DataGridRow to have PaleGreen background when Flag = 2 but the Value column should be red. I know that I can create a style for the flag column as thats not vislible this isn't helpful.

Sorry if this is a newbie question.  First foray into wpf from WinForms.

What I have so far:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Flag}" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="PaleGreen" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Flag}" Value="3">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="CadetBlue" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  Code for completeness

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Flag}" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="PaleGreen" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Flag}" Value="3">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="CadetBlue" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="ValueColumn">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Flag}" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Node" Binding="{Binding Path=Node}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="300" Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" CellStyle="{StaticResource ValueColumn}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Flag" Binding="{Binding Path=Flag}" Visibility="Hidden" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```